# Multiple asp:Repeater DataBind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am 90% certain I have acheived this before, but I cannot remember how I did it.

I have a repeater which I would like to use twice on a page as the structure and databinding events are the same, but the data binding to the repeater is obviously different.

In the past I believe I set the datasource on the repeater then databinded, and then did the same again but with another datasource, so effectively:

```
MyRepeater.DataSource = DataSourceOne;
MyRepeater.DataBind();
MyRepeater.DataSource = DataSourceTwo;
MyRepeater.DataBind();
```

Now this would have produced the html twice on the page. In this instance two lists, with different data contained inside of them.

Thinking about it, it could possibly the *type* of datasource used. Before it might of been a dataset/table I was binding to the repeater, but this time I am using an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList Items = new ArrayList();
Items = this.GetMenu(this._ProductsPageID);
this.rep_ProductsPortfolio.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(ProdPortItemDataBound);
this.rep_ProductsPortfolio.DataSource = Items;
this.rep_ProductsPortfolio.DataBind();

// Get portfolio
Items = this.GetMenu(this._PortfolioPageID);
this.rep_ProductsPortfolio.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(ProdPortItemDataBound);
this.rep_ProductsPortfolio.DataSource = Items;
this.rep_ProductsPortfolio.DataBind();
```

I have also tried using a different ArrayList for each repeater, but that didn't work either.

At the moment all that happens is the second databind is rebinding over the old repeater and I only have one on the page.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the DataSource it owerrite the first one.
My idea is to use two repeaters.

Comment: How can I use nested repeater for my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255119/how-to-populate-two-separate-repeaters-with-distinct-column-name-and-the-value-c

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure in the past you didn't use two repeaters with one datasource?

I think you need to use two repeaters here.

Comment: No, was different datasources :)

Comment: ...then I suspect you triggered a bug, or at least undefined behaviour that you shouldn't rely on.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone, I can't figure out how I did it before (if I even did!), the time I wasted creating this question and now responding to it is ten-fold to the solution.

In the end I have just made it all work with one datasource with the binding events being handled, and as the only thing that is changing is the data being bound I simply copied the repeater and renamed it and wired the other datasource to the new repeater and re-used the databinding events, taking a whole 1 minute... haha

In short, can't be done, use **two repeaters** and **one binding event handler**

Thanks anyway everyone! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Dataset/tables, but I always used ArrayLists as DataSource of my Repeaters, and never got it duplicated.

But it seems unresonable the fact of one Repeater creating two tables in HTML code =O

Anyway, setting the DataSource is replacing the reference and not "appending" it =)

Edit:

From MSDN documentation:

Repeater.DataSource Property: **Gets or sets** the data source that provides data for populating the list.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, what you're doing will overwrite the output of the first databind.

But you could combine the lists before you databind them

```
var allItems = new List<Foo>();
allItems.AddRange(fooDataSource1);
allItems.AddRange(fooDataSource2);
repeater1.Datsource = allItems;
repeater1.Databind();
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I was changing a class on the UL for each datasource, so sadly I can't bind one big dataset :(

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** Setting the DataSource is replacing the reference and not "appending"

**Proposed Fix:**
What you can consider is use multiple DataTables and then Merge your DataTables before you set the Repeaters DataSource. And thereafter you DataBind to the Repeater :)

**Steps**:
**1) Create 2 public DataTables**

```
public DataTable DT1 = new DataTable();
public DataTable DT2= new DataTable();
```

**2) DataBind your data in DT1-->**

```
DBConnect con = new DBConnect();
DT1 = con.GetDT1();

Repeater1.DataSource = DT1;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

**3) DataBind your data in DT2 and merge into DT1**

```
DBConnect con = new DBConnect();
DT2 = con.GetDT2Data();
DT1.Merge(DT2);

Repeater1.DataSource = DT1;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And there we go. We have "Appended" our data.

Comment: Try using code blocks for your code to make it more readable.

I.e. you can `write code like this`. Just use the ` to do so