# How to populate two separate repeaters with distinct column name and the value corresponding to the column

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to populate a repeater with two separate list

I have the following repeater:

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptLabels" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="hidOverflow setFloatL smallPadLeft" style="width: 45%; float: left;">

        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="hidOverflow smallPad">
                    <div class="setFloatL halfWidth vertAlignT">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="setFloatL vertAlignT">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptLabels2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="hidOverflow setFloatL smallPadLeft" style="width: 45%; float: left;">

        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="hidOverflow smallPad">
                    <div class="setFloatL halfWidth vertAlignT">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl3" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="setFloatL vertAlignT">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl4" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

I am trying to populate the column name into each `lbl1` and the row value of the corresponding column into each `lbl2`. I have the following code:

```
List<string> colO = new List<string>();
List<string> colOV = new List<string>();
List<string> colT = new List<string>();
List<string> colTV = new List<string>();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(gloString))
{

    string strQuery = @""; //query which generates the dataset

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);

        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(myDataSet);


        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
        myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];

        for (i = 0; i < myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count / 2; i++)
        {
            lop += myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName + " ";
            colO.Add(myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString()); //column name
            colOV.Add(myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][i].ToString()); //row value of the column
        }
        lop += "\n\n";
        for (int j = i; j < myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            lop += myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[j].ColumnName + " ";
            colT.Add(myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString()); //column name
            colTV.Add(myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][j].ToString()); //row value of the column
        }

        rptLabels.DataSource = colO; //I would like to popupate "colO" into "lbl1" and "colOV" into "lbl2" inside "rptLabels" repeater
        rptLabels.DataBind();

        rptLabels2.DataSource = colT; //I would like to popupate "colT" into "lbl3" and "colTV" into "lbl4" inside "rptLabels2" repeater
        rptLabels2.DataBind();
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
    }
}
```

Right now I can only use one list for the datasource for each repeater. How can I modify the code to achieve the following:

```
rptLabels.DataSource = colO; //I would like to popupate "colO" into "lbl1" and "colOV" into "lbl2" inside "rptLabels" repeater
rptLabels.DataBind();

rptLabels2.DataSource = colT; //I would like to popupate "colT" into "lbl3" and "colTV" into "lbl4" inside "rptLabels2" repeater
rptLabels2.DataBind();
```

Comment: Updated my question with clarification.

Comment: You might want to let us know exactly what you're trying to achieve since your approach may not be a good one to start with. (I.e. show us the data structure and how you would like to display it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataTable` could to be accessed in the form of `array of muti-dimension`, besides being the most briefly to access rows and columns. For example:

```
myDt.Rows[0][0]; // access the first row and first column
myDt.Rows[0][1]; // access the first row and second column
myDt.Rows[0][2]; // access the first row and third column
myDt.Rows[1][0]; // access the second row and first column
myDt.Rows[1][1]; // access the second row and second column
myDt.Rows[1][2]; // access the second row and third column
```

If you need can go all fields returned using two nested `for` statement:

```
for(int i = 0;i < dtData.Rows.Count;i++)//travels the rows
{
     for(int j = 0;j < dtData.Rows.Count;j++)//travels the columns
     {
          var valueField = myDt.Rows[i][j];//access the value of current field
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each row contains individual columns. You can access it through
    Rows[i].ItemArray

Comment: It will always return one row.

Comment: I would like to get the row value of the column the iteration is currently in.

Comment: A row contains many values.  Use the ItemArray.  myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j] would be my guess

Comment: `i` and `j` are different for loop.

Comment: Then you are not understanding that you need two loops.  One to go through each of the rows you have, and one to go through each of the columns in that row (which is what itemarray is)